# Where is my object allocation and memory leak in this iPhone/objective C code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm still a rookie when it comes to this programming gig and was wondering if someone could help me smooth out this code. Functionally, the code works great and does what I need it to do. But when I run the performance tool the allocation graph peaks, the CPU load is high, there's a leak(s), and I've also confirmed when running on my iPhone it seems noticeably slower then the rest of the components in my app.

I'd appreciate any advice/tips/help anyone could give me. :)

Thanks in advance!

.h file

```
//
//  Time_CalculatorViewController.h
//  Time Calculator
//
//  Created by Adam Soloway on 2/19/10.
//  Copyright Legacy Pilots 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Time_CalculatorViewController : UIViewController {
 //BOOL         moveViewUp;
 //CGFloat      scrollAmount;

 IBOutlet UILabel *hoursLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *minutesLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *hoursDecimalLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *minutesDecimalLabel;
 IBOutlet UILabel *errorLabel;

 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField1;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField2;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField3;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField4;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField5;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField6;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField7;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField8;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField9;
 IBOutlet UITextField *minTextField10;

 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField1;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField2;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField3;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField4;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField5;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField6;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField7;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField8;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField9;
 IBOutlet UITextField *hourTextField10;

 IBOutlet UIButton *resetAll;


 NSString *minutesString1;
 NSString *minutesString2;
 NSString *minutesString3;
 NSString *minutesString4;
 NSString *minutesString5;
 NSString *minutesString6;
 NSString *minutesString7;
 NSString *minutesString8;
 NSString *minutesString9;
 NSString *minutesString10;

 NSString *hoursString1;
 NSString *hoursString2;
 NSString *hoursString3;
 NSString *hoursString4;
 NSString *hoursString5;
 NSString *hoursString6;
 NSString *hoursString7;
 NSString *hoursString8;
 NSString *hoursString9;
 NSString *hoursString10;

 int hourDecimalNumber;
 int totalTime;
 int leftOverMinutes;


 int minuteNumber1;
 int minuteNumber2;
 int minuteNumber3;
 int minuteNumber4;
 int minuteNumber5;
 int minuteNumber6;
 int minuteNumber7;
 int minuteNumber8;
 int minuteNumber9;
 int minuteNumber10;

 int hourNumber1;
 int hourNumber2;
 int hourNumber3;
 int hourNumber4;
 int hourNumber5;
 int hourNumber6;
 int hourNumber7;
 int hourNumber8;
 int hourNumber9;
 int hourNumber10;

}

//- (void)scrollTheView:(BOOL)movedUp;
- (void)calculateTime;
- (IBAction)resetAllValues;


@end
```

.m file

```
    //
//  Time_CalculatorViewController.m
//  Time Calculator
//
//  Created by Adam Soloway on 2/19/10.
//  Copyright Legacy Pilots 2010. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Time_CalculatorViewController.h"

@implementation Time_CalculatorViewController





- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

 if( minTextField1.editing || minTextField2.editing || minTextField3.editing || minTextField4.editing || minTextField5.editing || minTextField6.editing || minTextField7.editing || minTextField8.editing || minTextField9.editing || minTextField10.editing || hourTextField1.editing || hourTextField2.editing || hourTextField3.editing || hourTextField4.editing || hourTextField5.editing || hourTextField6.editing || hourTextField7.editing || hourTextField8.editing || hourTextField9.editing || hourTextField10.editing) {
  [minTextField1 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField2 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField3 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField4 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField5 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField6 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField7 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField8 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField9 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [minTextField10 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField1 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField2 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField3 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField4 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField5 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField6 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField7 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField8 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField9 resignFirstResponder]; 
  [hourTextField10 resignFirstResponder];
  [self calculateTime];
  //if (moveViewUp) [self scrollTheView:NO];
 }
 [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}



/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
 // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [minutesString1 release];
 [minutesString2 release];
 [minutesString3 release];
 [minutesString4 release];
 [minutesString5 release];
 [minutesString6 release];
 [minutesString7 release];
 [minutesString8 release];
 [minutesString9 release];
 [minutesString10 release];

 [hoursString1 release];
 [hoursString2 release];
 [hoursString3 release];
 [hoursString4 release];
 [hoursString5 release];
 [hoursString6 release];
 [hoursString7 release];
 [hoursString8 release];
 [hoursString9 release];
 [hoursString10 release];


    [super dealloc];
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

 //[minTextField10 resignFirstResponder];
 //if (moveViewUp) [self scrollTheView:NO]; 
 [self calculateTime];
 return YES;
}

- (IBAction)resetAllValues
{
 minTextField1.text = 0;
 minTextField2.text = 0;
 minTextField3.text = 0;
 minTextField4.text = 0;
 minTextField5.text = 0;
 minTextField6.text = 0;
 minTextField7.text = 0;
 minTextField8.text = 0;
 minTextField9.text = 0;
 minTextField10.text = 0;

 hourTextField1.text = 0;
 hourTextField2.text = 0;
 hourTextField3.text = 0;
 hourTextField4.text = 0;
 hourTextField5.text = 0;
 hourTextField6.text = 0;
 hourTextField7.text = 0;
 hourTextField8.text = 0;
 hourTextField9.text = 0;
 hourTextField10.text = 0;

 totalTime = 0;
 leftOverMinutes = 0;
 hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
 hourDecimalNumber = 0;
 hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
 minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];

 self.calculateTime;
}


- (void)calculateTime {

 minutesString1 = minTextField1.text;
 minutesString2 = minTextField2.text;
 minutesString3 = minTextField3.text;
 minutesString4 = minTextField4.text;
 minutesString5 = minTextField5.text;
 minutesString6 = minTextField6.text;
 minutesString7 = minTextField7.text;
 minutesString8 = minTextField8.text;
 minutesString9 = minTextField9.text;
 minutesString10 = minTextField10.text;

 hoursString1 = hourTextField1.text;
 hoursString2 = hourTextField2.text;
 hoursString3 = hourTextField3.text;
 hoursString4 = hourTextField4.text;
 hoursString5 = hourTextField5.text;
 hoursString6 = hourTextField6.text;
 hoursString7 = hourTextField7.text;
 hoursString8 = hourTextField8.text;
 hoursString9 = hourTextField9.text;
 hoursString10 = hourTextField10.text;

 minuteNumber1 = [minutesString1 intValue];
 minuteNumber2 = [minutesString2 intValue];
 minuteNumber3 = [minutesString3 intValue];
 minuteNumber4 = [minutesString4 intValue];
 minuteNumber5 = [minutesString5 intValue];
 minuteNumber6 = [minutesString6 intValue];
 minuteNumber7 = [minutesString7 intValue];
 minuteNumber8 = [minutesString8 intValue];
 minuteNumber9 = [minutesString9 intValue];
 minuteNumber10 = [minutesString10 intValue];

 hourNumber1 = ([hoursString1 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber2 = ([hoursString2 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber3 = ([hoursString3 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber4 = ([hoursString4 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber5 = ([hoursString5 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber6 = ([hoursString6 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber7 = ([hoursString7 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber8 = ([hoursString8 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber9 = ([hoursString9 intValue] * 60);
 hourNumber10 = ([hoursString10 intValue] * 60);

 totalTime = (hourNumber1 + hourNumber2 +hourNumber3 +hourNumber4 +hourNumber5 +hourNumber6 +hourNumber7 +hourNumber8 +hourNumber9 +hourNumber10 + minuteNumber1 + minuteNumber2 + minuteNumber3 + minuteNumber4 + minuteNumber5 +minuteNumber6 + minuteNumber7 + minuteNumber8 + minuteNumber9 + minuteNumber10);

 if (totalTime <= 59) {
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 0;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;
 }

 else if (totalTime >59 && totalTime <= 119){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 60;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 1;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;
 }

 else if (totalTime >119 && totalTime <= 179){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 120;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 2;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;
 }

 else if (totalTime >179 && totalTime <= 239){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 180;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 3;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;

 }

 else if (totalTime >239 && totalTime <= 299){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 240;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 4;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >299 && totalTime <= 359){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 300;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 5;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >359 && totalTime <= 419){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 360;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 6;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >419 && totalTime <= 479){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 420;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 7;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >479 && totalTime <= 539){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 480;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"8"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 8;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >539 && totalTime <= 599){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 540;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"9"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 9;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >599 && totalTime <= 659){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 600;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"10"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 10;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >659 && totalTime <= 719){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 660;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 11;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >719 && totalTime <= 779){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 720;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 12;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >779 && totalTime <= 839){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 780;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"13"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 13;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >839 && totalTime <= 899){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 840;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"14"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 14;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >899 && totalTime <= 959){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 900;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"15"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 15;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >959 && totalTime <= 1019){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 960;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"16"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 16;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1019 && totalTime <= 1079){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1020;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"17"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 17;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1079 && totalTime <= 1139){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1080;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"18"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 18;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1139 && totalTime <= 1199){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1140;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"19"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 19;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1199 && totalTime <= 1259){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1200;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"20"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 20;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1259 && totalTime <= 1319){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1260;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"21"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 21;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1319 && totalTime <= 1379){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1320;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"22"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 22;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1379 && totalTime <= 1439){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1380;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"23"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 23;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1439 && totalTime <= 1499){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1440;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"24"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 24;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1499 && totalTime <= 1559){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1500;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"25"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 25;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1559 && totalTime <= 1619){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1560;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"26"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 26;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1619 && totalTime <= 1679){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1620;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"27"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 27;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }


 else if (totalTime >1679 && totalTime <= 1739){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1680;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"28"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 28;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1739 && totalTime <= 1799){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1740;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"29"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 29;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }

 else if (totalTime >1799 && totalTime <= 1859){
  leftOverMinutes = totalTime - 1800;
  hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"30"];
  hourDecimalNumber = 30;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
  errorLabel.hidden = TRUE;


 }
 else if (totalTime >1859){
   hoursLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error"];
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error"];
  errorLabel.hidden = FALSE;
 }


  //Minutes Label 
 if (leftOverMinutes < 10) {
  minutesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d", leftOverMinutes];
 }
 else 
  minutesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", leftOverMinutes];


 //Minutes Decimal Label
 if (leftOverMinutes >=0 && leftOverMinutes <=2) {
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=3 && leftOverMinutes <=8){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=9 && leftOverMinutes <=14){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=15 && leftOverMinutes <=20){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=21 && leftOverMinutes <=26){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"4"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=27 && leftOverMinutes <=32){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=33 && leftOverMinutes <=38){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"6"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=39 && leftOverMinutes <=44){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"7"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=45 && leftOverMinutes <=50){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"8"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=51 && leftOverMinutes <=56){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"9"];
 }
 else if (leftOverMinutes >=57 && leftOverMinutes <=60){
  minutesDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
  hourDecimalNumber = hourDecimalNumber + 1;
  hoursDecimalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hourDecimalNumber];
 }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the details of the leak — you might edit this post to add a copy of the stack trace from Instruments, where the leak occurs. This will tell you in which method your leak is occurring. Nonetheless, if you double-click on the leak in Instruments, it can bring up where the leak occurs in source, assuming the leak is with your code.

Answer (score 0):

`IBOutlets` are retained on the iPhone--they should be released when you dealloc the class, otherwise they will leak (see [here](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=95)).  Also, I'd recommend you look at Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)--there seem to be quite a few problems in your code (strings, for instance, usually don't have to be released).

Comment: I think they should be left equal to nil, not explicitly released, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @Mr.Gando: It's rather annoying, but based on Apple's recommendations, they should be set to `nil` in `viewDidUnload` (which is only called for memory warnings), and explicitly released in `dealloc` (since Apple recommends against using accessors in `dealloc`).  It's probably fine to set them to nil both times, though.